# On the GCD of two palindromes.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, palindrome

I had an observation. Which I will discuss below. My question will be Is my observation correct? If so, how can one prove it?

Observation:

Consider the string of palindromes below:

$100...01$ and $111...11$

I observed that:

$gcd(100...01,111...11)=1$ if the length of the string is odd while

$gcd(100...01,111...11)=11$ if the length of the string is even.

Thank you so much for the big help.

Comment: Well, first, let's make the problem a bit more rigorous (i.e. no ellipses). This is the the GCD you are talking about: $$\text{gcd}\left(10^k+1, \sum_{i=0}^k 10^k\right)$$ The "string length" is $k+1$, so we want to prove that the GCD equals $1$ if $k$ is even and $11$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: ... and the next step is to note that $$\sum_{i=0}^k 10^k = \dfrac{10^{k+1}-1}{9}$$
and that $10^k+1$ is not divisible by $3$.

Comment: @NobleMushtak thank you for the restatement of the problem. You were right.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Thanks, I both agree with the identity above as well as the note that 3 does not divides $10^k+1$. But I do not know what comes next, that is, what is its implications? Can you explain further Sir?

Comment: The gcd is $\gcd(10^k+1, 10^{k+1}-1)$, since multiplying the second term by $9$ doesn't introduce any extra factors.  Now add the first term to the second: it's $\gcd(10^k+1, 10^{k+1}+10^k)$.  But $10^{k+1}+10^k = 11 \times 10^k$, and $10^k+1$ and $10^k$ are coprime.  So the only possible common divisor other than $1$ is $11$.

Comment: Now I understand Sir @RobertIsrael. thank you for the big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm about to do below is called the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). If you're not familiar with it, I can show you some explanations of it on other questions/Web sites if you ask me in the comments.

We have:
$$\text{gcd}\left(10^k+1, \sum_{i=0}^k 10^k\right)$$
The second element is bigger, so subtract it by the first element:
$$\text{gcd}\left(10^k+1, \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 10^k\right)$$
Notice how the second element now has no ones place or $10^k$ place. Now, the first element is bigger, so subtract it by the second element, which affects all of the digits of the first element except the first and the last:
$$\text{gcd}\left(91+\sum_{i=2}^{k-1} 8\cdot 10^k, \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 10^k\right)$$
Notice how I changed the summation index from $i=1$ to $i=2$ and brought the tens place out into to make $91$ in front. Now, do this $8$ more times, getting rid of the summation and subtracting $91$ by $80$ which gives us $11$:
$$\text{gcd}\left(11, \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} 10^k\right)$$

Now, $11$ is prime so the GCD is either $1$ or $11$:

- If $k$ is even, then we have an odd number of $1$s in the second element and it is not divisible by $11$, so the GCD is $1$.
- If $k$ is odd, then we have an even number of $1$s in the second element and it is divisible by $11$, so the GCD is $11$.

Thus, since I just proved [a restatement of your observation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793615/on-the-gcd-of-two-palindromes#comment3661640_1793615), your observation was indeed correct. Good job!

Comment: Thank you so much @NobleMushtak. Brilliant! I will study your answer in a while. Thank you so much again for the big help. An upvote for now.

Comment: Thank you so much @NobleMushtak

Comment: @JrAntalan I'm glad I could help you! It was a fun problem!

Comment: I had a lot of fun also. Till next time.